# Addition of list and NumPy number

Tags: python, list, numpy

If you add an integer to a list, you get an error raised by the __add__ function of the list (I suppose):

```
>>> [1,2,3] + 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

If you add a list to a NumPy array, I assume that the __add__ function of the NumPy array converts the list to a NumPy array and adds the lists

```
>>> np.array([3]) + [1,2,3]
array([4, 5, 6])
```

But what happens in the following?

```
>>> [1,2,3] + np.array([3])
array([4, 5, 6])
```

How does the list know how to handle addition with NumPy arrays?

Comment: *"How does the list know how to handle addition with numpy arrays."* - it doesn't, `[1,2,3].__add__(np.array([3]))` will fail, but Python reverses the arguments if the first attempt fails and `np.array([3]).__radd__([1,2,3])` (`__add__` is called if `__radd__` isn't defined) works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Shouldn't rather `__radd__` be called?

Comment: @Christoph if it's defined, yes; clarified

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't think `a + b` will ever call `b.__add__`. Python doesn't assume that addition is commutative. You may be thinking of the augmented assignment operators, where `a += b` will first try `a.__iadd__`, but then fall back to `__add__` (and further to `b.__radd__`) if necessary.

Comment: @Blckknght you're absolutely right, I guess that's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`list` does not know how to handle addition with NumPy arrays. Even in `[1,2,3] + np.array([3])`, it's NumPy arrays that handle the addition.

As [documented in the data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules):

> - For objects x and y, first `x.__op__(y)` is tried. If this is not implemented or returns NotImplemented, `y.__rop__(x)` is tried. If
>     this is also not implemented or returns NotImplemented, a TypeError
>     exception is raised. But see the following exception:
> - Exception to the previous item: if the left operand is an instance of a built-in type or a new-style class, and the right operand is an
>     instance of a proper subclass of that type or class and overrides the
>     base’s `__rop__()` method, the right operand’s `__rop__()` method is
>     tried before the left operand’s `__op__()` method.

When you do

```
[1,2,3] + np.array([3])
```

what is internally called is

```
np.array([3]).__radd__([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 8):

It is because of the `__radd__` method of np.array, check out this link : http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric (paragraph Reflected arithmetic operators).

In facts, when you try `[1,2,3].__add__(np.array([3]))`, it raises an error, so `np.array([3]).__radd__([1,2,3])` is called.